# Why is my EXR showing up lighter than expected in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, color-conversion

I have a 32-bit EXR image that's supposed to show the following color:

```
r: 0.5
g: 0.5
b: 1.0
```

each color channel is in the [0, 1] range. When I open the EXR file in Photoshop, this is what I see:

[image]

You'll notice that the color picker accurately lists `r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 1.0`, but visually it's much lighter than it should be. A color of those values should look more purple, like this:

[image]

The problem is that I need to take the 32-bit EXR and convert to 8-bit PNG, but it's coming out much lighter than it should. Instead of getting the color I need `#8080ff`, I'm getting the lighter `#bcbcff`. Do I need to do gamma correction, or some sort of linear-space conversion? I believe this question is very similar [to this question for GIMP](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109847/32-bit-float-exr-with-gimp-photoshop), but that one doesn't have an answer either.

Comment: set working space to something linear

Comment: @joojaa ok, how?

Comment: Edit > Color settings. Unfortunately your unlikely to have a linear profile on your computer since no image ever is linear.

Comment: When viewing a 32 bit image on a normal computer monitor in Photoshop, you can't see the full tonal range in the image, so basically what you are seeing on-screen is not fully representative of the colour information in the image.  If you want to convert a 32bit image to  PNG24 (i.e 8 bit per channel), you will have to tone map it in some way. See [this page on the Adobe Support forum for more info](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/converting-images-from-32-bit-to-16-bit/td-p/9189135?page=1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way I was able to convert a 32-bit `.exr` normal map into an 8-bit `.png` normal map is by opening a second file with 8-bit RGB mode and copy/pasting the individual channels.

Open the channels tab (next to Layers) and:

- copy `.exr` red channel -> paste into `.png`'s red channel.
- copy `.exr` blue channel -> paste into `.png`'s blue channel.
- copy `.exr` green channel -> paste into `.png`'s green channel.

Now you can see, the color that was `0.5, 0.5, 1.0` in the EXR file is now `128, 128, 255` in PNG, as desired:
[image]